# graph API only works for /me/feed not {user-id}/feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Javascript SDK to access user feed. When I put FB.api('/me/posts'), it returns correct result. But if I substitute me with some {user-id} or even my own ID, it returns "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api". 
I thought it should work at least for my own user ID, but it did not :(

I have grant user permission for 'user_about_me,user_birthday,user_events,user_friends,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_status,user_videos,email,publish_actions,user_posts'

Can anyone help with this?

A billion thanks!

Comment: Are you using the ID `/me` returns? IDs are application specific.

Comment: How to find those app specific IDs?

Comment: When your user connects, make an API call to `/me` and get the `id` value from it.

Comment: Great! I got it to work. One more question, are there ways to get other users' app specific id?

Comment: Call `/me` with their access token.